# How to effectively log 100s to 1000s of actions to a database

Tags: c#, database, performance, fluent-nhibernate

I currently have a scenario where a 1000 actions could occur in a matter of seconds and I need to store all these actions in a database.

What I currently do is keep a idle timer, once this timer reaches a pre-defined time, I take the cached actions (actions since last commit - which is just a simple list) and commit those actions to the database.

The UI needs to be responsive as possible (duh?).

Other than pushing the database logging to a seperate thread, are there any other suggestions with regards to performance that anyone can help me out with?

Comment: "100s to 1000s actions could occur in a matter of seconds" - that's not that many!

Comment: I'm all for the separate thread and concurrent-safe queue idea. Simple. Clean. (The writer thread may batch off the queue if it can, but otherwise, KISS.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using 3rd party logging frameworks like [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/wiki/AsyncWrapper_target) which have asynchronous logging wrapper.

Answer (score 2):

Log the actions to the tail of a log file as the actions occur. This has two benefits. It is real fast and so your UI is still responsive and it means that if the application crashes the actions are not lost.

Then have a background thread that takes the actions in the file and updates the database. After your application crashes you can restart and the background thread simply updates with the actions that were safely saved in the past. You could even have a separate application/process/windows service that does the background update and have the UI application only perform log writing.

If you really must avoid a separate thread then you would need to perform the database udpates in very small batches, so they are as quick as possible, and in idle time processing. But this approach is always going to be inferior because the database operation becomes synchronous with your UI. So your UI hangs for the duration. Any database problem such as a timeout due to connectivity problems then kills the UI.